# What are ethereum contract wallets

Tags: contract-design, wallets, out-of-gas, wallet-transfer

Recently I had used shapeshift to exchange ethereum for ripple but the transaction failed and wasn’t able to get a refund back to my wallet  due to out of gas. i need to provide shapeshift another ETH address that does not have contract restrictions.May i Know what are contract wallets please?

Answer (score 1):

- **May i Know what are contract wallets please?**

It is exactly what a wallet is. Contract have an address, like wallets. They can have ether as well and transfer some.

- **the transaction failed and wasn’t able to get a refund back to my
  wallet due to out of gas**

You only lost gas used because you did not set your gas limit high enough. It's like using a car to go from A to B without having enough gas for the trip.

- **i need to provide shapeshift another ETH address that does not have
  contract restrictions**

This is not a contract restriction, it is the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM). Every action that is done by a contract function, if it changes the EVM, costs gas. So let say you change the value of an Integer, you must pay for that (they are called transactions). But some functions (constant functions) that do not change anything but only return you a value are free, they are called "calls"